# mvc 5 and validating model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 and Entity Framework for a project.

I have a model in my project:

```
public class ContractViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Registration Number")]
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Scheduled End Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // check 1: Start Date should be before End Date
        if (StartDate != null && EndDate != null)
        {
            if (DateTime.Compare(StartDate.Value, EndDate.Value) > 0)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Start Date must be before End Date");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to have a few checks in there, Registration Number needs to be filled and not already exist.  Along with Start Date has to be before End Date.

Currently for Registration Number I have the Required Annotation there, for it not already existing, when I do my save I check it there and if it already exists I use:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Registration Number already exists.");
```

For the StartDate and EndData I used the Validate method from the IValidateObject interface.

The reason I did not do the Registration Number check in Validate method was I did not want that library (ProjectModels.dll) to reference Entity Framework.

Currently when the checks are done, they are not combined, so if Registration Number is not entered and EndDate is before StartDate, only the Registration Number validation is shown.

Is there anyway to get them to all show together?

Also the Required Annotation for Registration Number displays the error message under the field on the form, using the ValidationMessageFor property, is there anyway to get that to display for the other 2 when those errors occur?

Comment: I believe the default model binder validates the annotations and if the modelstate is invalid it doesnt trigger the validate method. You need to move the dataannotation's logic inside your validate method or write your own validation attributes inheriting from ValidationAttribute and remove the validate method. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @heymega yes that makes sense, i had a feeling i would have to move them all together.

Answer (score 0):

Writing sophisticated business rules that require custom code to go look up data by calling repository data access code can be fun and challenging.

There's a Nuget package called Foolproof that adds some more attributes that extend what you can do, but an excellent framework for creating business objects that has a really good rules engine worth checking out is CSLA.Net.